# App keeps going to home screen after clicking on a list item

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a quiz app where a category can be selected by clicking on a listView item. Each category has code like 0,1,2. For football, it is 0. After clicking on the football item, the app keeps on going to the home screen instead of logging the data I want. Please help me with the error.

> Quiz Category Selection Class

```
    String quizCategory = intent.getStringExtra("QuizCategory");

        //Deciding which database to Open and choose
        switch (quizCategory) {
            case "0":
                Log.i("Category", "Football");
                Football football = new Football(this);
                football.createDatabase();
                football.openDatabase();
                football.getWritableDatabase();
long x=football.getRowCount();
                break;
            default:
                Log.i("Message", "Error");

        }
    }
```

> Football Class

```
    public class Football extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String Database_path = "/data/data/com.google.quiz/databases/";
    private static final String Database_name = "football.db";
    private static Context context;
    private static final int version = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase sqlite;

    public Football(Context context) {
        super(context, Database_name, null, version);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void createDatabase() {
        createDB();
    }

    private void createDB() {
        boolean dbexist = DBexists();
        if (!dbexist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDBfromResource();
        }
    }

    private void copyDBfromResource() {
        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;
        String filePath = Database_path + Database_name;
        try {
            is = context.getAssets().open(Database_name);//reading purpose
            os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);//writing purpose
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);//writing to file
            }
            os.flush();//flush the outputstream
            is.close();//close the inputstream
            os.close();//close the outputstream

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Problem copying database file:");
        }
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = Database_path + Database_name;
        sqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    private boolean DBexists() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            String databasePath = Database_path + Database_name;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setVersion(1);
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Sqlite", "Database not found");
        }
        if (db != null)
            db.close();///close the opened file
        return db != null ? true : false;
    }
public long getRowCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        long x = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "football");
        db.close();
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the value of `quizCategory` before your switch?

Comment: Yes, it prints Football after the item is clikced.

Comment: Shouldn't it print 0 if you want your switch case to work?

Comment: I am printing Football if it recieves 0.

Comment: Do you have any errors or caught exceptions in your log?

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: football (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from football
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)